# Why is `switch` so slow?

Tags: c, switch-statement, function-pointers, goto

In a bytecode interpreting loop, after several tests, I'm surprised to see that using `switch` is the worst choice to make. Making calls to a function pointer array, or using gcc's computed `goto` extension is always 10~20% faster, the computed `goto` version being the fastest. I've tested with my real toy VM with 97 instructions and with the mini fake VM pasted below.

Why is using `switch` the slowest?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <time.h>

enum {
    ADD1 = 1,
    ADD2,
    SUB3,
    SUB4,
    MUL5,
    MUL6,
};

static unsigned int number;

static void add1(void) {
    number += 1;
}

static void add2(void) {
    number += 2;
}

static void sub3(void) {
    number -= 3;
}

static void sub4(void) {
    number -= 4;
}

static void mul5(void) {
    number *= 5;
}

static void mul6(void) {
    number *= 6;
}

static void interpret_bytecodes_switch(uint8_t *bcs) {
    while (true) {
        switch (*bcs++) {
        case 0:
            return;
        case ADD1:
            add1();
            break;
        case ADD2:
            add2();
            break;
        case SUB3:
            sub3();
            break;
        case SUB4:
            sub4();
            break;
        case MUL5:
            mul5();
            break;
        case MUL6:
            mul6();
            break;
        }
    }
}

static void interpret_bytecodes_function_pointer(uint8_t *bcs) {
    void (*fs[])(void) = {
        NULL,
        add1,
        add2,
        sub3,
        sub4,
        mul5,
        mul6,
    };
    while (*bcs) {
        fs[*bcs++]();
    }
}

static void interpret_bytecodes_goto(uint8_t *bcs) {
    void *labels[] = {
        &&l_exit,
        &&l_add1,
        &&l_add2,
        &&l_sub3,
        &&l_sub4,
        &&l_mul5,
        &&l_mul6,
    };
    #define JUMP goto *labels[*bcs++]
    JUMP;
l_exit:
    return;
l_add1:
    add1();
    JUMP;
l_add2:
    add2();
    JUMP;
l_sub3:
    sub3();
    JUMP;
l_sub4:
    sub4();
    JUMP;
l_mul5:
    mul5();
    JUMP;
l_mul6:
    mul6();
    JUMP;
    #undef JUMP
}

struct timer {
    clock_t start, end;
};

static void timer_start(struct timer *self) {
    self->start = clock();
}

static void timer_end(struct timer *self) {
    self->end = clock();
}

static double timer_measure(struct timer *self) {
    return (double)(self->end - self->start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

static void test(void (*f)(uint8_t *), uint8_t *bcs) {
    number = 0;
    struct timer timer;
    timer_start(&timer);
    f(bcs);
    timer_end(&timer);
    printf("%u %.3fs\n", number, timer_measure(&timer));
}

int main(void) {
    const int N = 300000000;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    uint8_t *bcs = malloc(N + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        bcs[i] = rand() % 5 + 1;
    }
    bcs[N] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", bcs[i]);
    }
    printf("\nswitch\n");
    test(interpret_bytecodes_switch, bcs);
    printf("function pointer\n");
    test(interpret_bytecodes_function_pointer, bcs);
    printf("goto\n");
    test(interpret_bytecodes_goto, bcs);
    return 0;
}
```

**result**

```
~$ gcc vm.c -ovm -std=gnu11 -O3
~$ ./vm
3 4 5 3 3 5 3 3 1 2 
switch
3050839589 2.866s
function pointer
3050839589 2.573s
goto
3050839589 2.433s
~$ ./vm
3 1 1 3 5 5 2 4 5 1 
switch
3898179583 2.871s
function pointer
3898179583 2.573s
goto
3898179583 2.431s
~$ ./vm
5 5 1 2 3 3 1 2 2 4 
switch
954521520 2.869s
function pointer
954521520 2.574s
goto
954521520 2.432s
```

Below is the relevant disassembly of the code posted here after `-O3` optimization.

```
interpret_bytecodes_switch:
.L8:
    addq    $1, %rdi
    cmpb    $6, -1(%rdi)
    ja  .L8
    movzbl  -1(%rdi), %edx
    jmp *.L11(,%rdx,8)
.L11:
    .quad   .L10
    .quad   .L12
    .quad   .L13
    .quad   .L14
    .quad   .L15
    .quad   .L16
    .quad   .L17
.L16:
    leal    (%rax,%rax,4), %eax
    jmp .L8
.L15:
    subl    $4, %eax
    jmp .L8
.L14:
    subl    $3, %eax
    jmp .L8
.L13:
    addl    $2, %eax
    jmp .L8
.L12:
    addl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L8
.L10:
    movl    %eax, number(%rip)
    ret
.L17:
    leal    (%rax,%rax,2), %eax
    addl    %eax, %eax
    jmp .L8

interpret_bytecodes_function_pointer:
    pushq   %rbx
    movq    %rdi, %rbx
    subq    $64, %rsp
    movzbl  (%rdi), %eax
    movq    $0, (%rsp)
    movq    $add1, 8(%rsp)
    movq    $add2, 16(%rsp)
    movq    $sub3, 24(%rsp)
    movq    $sub4, 32(%rsp)
    movq    $mul5, 40(%rsp)
    testb   %al, %al
    movq    $mul6, 48(%rsp)
    je  .L19
.L23:
    addq    $1, %rbx
    call    *(%rsp,%rax,8)
    movzbl  (%rbx), %eax
    testb   %al, %al
    jne .L23
.L19:
    addq    $64, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    ret

interpret_bytecodes_goto:
    movzbl  (%rdi), %eax
    movq    $.L27, -72(%rsp)
    addq    $2, %rdi
    movq    $.L28, -64(%rsp)
    movq    $.L29, -56(%rsp)
    movq    $.L30, -48(%rsp)
    movq    $.L31, -40(%rsp)
    movq    $.L32, -32(%rsp)
    movq    $.L33, -24(%rsp)
    movq    -72(%rsp,%rax,8), %rax
    jmp *%rax
.L33:
    movl    number(%rip), %eax
    leal    (%rax,%rax,2), %eax
    addl    %eax, %eax
    movl    %eax, number(%rip)
    movzbl  -1(%rdi), %eax
    movq    -72(%rsp,%rax,8), %rax
.L35:
    addq    $1, %rdi
    jmp *%rax
.L28:
    addl    $1, number(%rip)
    movzbl  -1(%rdi), %eax
    movq    -72(%rsp,%rax,8), %rax
    jmp .L35
.L30:
    subl    $3, number(%rip)
    movzbl  -1(%rdi), %eax
    movq    -72(%rsp,%rax,8), %rax
    jmp .L35
.L31:
    subl    $4, number(%rip)
    movzbl  -1(%rdi), %eax
    movq    -72(%rsp,%rax,8), %rax
    jmp .L35
.L32:
    movl    number(%rip), %eax
    leal    (%rax,%rax,4), %eax
    movl    %eax, number(%rip)
    movzbl  -1(%rdi), %eax
    movq    -72(%rsp,%rax,8), %rax
    jmp .L35
.L29:
    addl    $2, number(%rip)
    movzbl  -1(%rdi), %eax
    movq    -72(%rsp,%rax,8), %rax
    jmp .L35
.L27:
    rep ret
```

Comment: Try `inline` on the functions and benchmark again.

Comment: @Olaf The functions are already inlined with `-O3`.

Comment: Not sure, as you use them multiple times and take their address; this might hinder inlining even at `-O3` - there is no guarantee, even _with_ the keyword (you might try `__attribute__((always_inline))`. Did you actually verify? What does the assembler code look like? Which architecture? Note that `switch` might care about `default` case (although not given), while your `gote` does not.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does your performance improve if you change your switch test to use `while (*bcs++) { switch (*bcs) {`?  The `while (true)` infinite loop might be messing with the optimizer.

Comment: I'm curious - can you reorder the tests so that switch isn't tested first, then let us know if you're still seeing this? The slowdown might be due to cache effects (perhaps the code isn't fully loaded into cache when you begin the test, making the switch statement look slower?)

Comment: @Mr.Llama Interesting! The difference is much less with your suggestion, but still the computed `goto` version 5~10% faster.

Comment: @templatetypedef No difference.

Comment: @Mr.Llama goto 4.096s, function pointer 4.286s, switch 4.241s with your optimization applied and with `N = 500000000`. Multiple runs give similar results.

Comment: My recommendation would be to look at the assembly and identify the differences between the various versions of the code. You might find some glaring flaw in the generated assembly and tweak the switch version until you get comparable performances. Without the assembly, you're mostly just making wild guesses which won't get you anywhere. Do note that the generated assembly may vary wildly between compilers and compiler versions but that is the price to pay when doing micro-optimizations.

Comment: It might be because the switch statement generates indirect branches and the other options use direct branches (I don't have time now to check if that's true or not).  If you are interested you might want to check this paper and see if it applies to what you are testing: https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01100647/document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`switch` is slowest because it has to manage `default` cases and this may add an extra bounds test you didn't implemented.

`switch` also handles a more general case where case values are not arranged in a so simple sequence, extra computation may be needed for that.

Comment: Agreed, but how is that effected if the compiler sees the terminating `break;` at the end of each statement? Then `switch` no longer daisy-chains each statement with default. (I don't know, I'm asking....)

Comment: Yes, the "goto" and "function pointer" methods both crash on a bad opcode. The "switch" method handles a bad opcode gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

I was in the middle of writing a long answer when you posted the assembly code...
Basically, the goto version uses more "code" to prevent a few (or a single) instructions in each iteration. It's similar to a size vs. speed optimization.

Since your "real work" is negligible, it makes enough of a difference in the benchmark, but in a real world scenario that instruction will become negligible.

Comment: Does editing my post make your previous writing gone? What happened?

Comment: It just became quite redundant since your update shows what I was trying to point out. In fact if you wanted to shave an extra instruction, you could have "inlined" the code in L35 and save that extra jump (I thought that's what the compiler actually did till you showed the code)

Answer (score 0):

You are performing a micro benchmark. Micro benchmarks on modern CPUs can be affected by all kinds of random or unpredicatable effects. There is actually very little difference in execution time. However, in order to make the code comparable, you combined switch and function calls, which in real life wouldn't happen for time critical code.

Comment: There is no real function calls, they are all just inlined. Should I post the assembly?

Comment: Micro benchmarks have limited use  in determining actual application performance. But they are less susceptible to random variation than larger benchmarks, and the results from the OP appear to be repeatable.